# How to import user address profiles into Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce, users, feeds

I have users with their profiles in a CSV file, state, street, phone... etc.

I tried using feeds to import this into Commerce, but it does not work. The profiles are not attached to users. I did a 2 step process with 2 feeds importers, but it isn't working, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Migrate module is the best way to import those things.